# Как остановить видео при начале проигрывания другого?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть слайдер с видео, которые вставляются в `<iframe>`.
Необходимо останавливать уже проигрывающееся видео при включении любого другого.

Пробовал так:

```
$('.video .slides li').change(function() {
    $('video').contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"onclick","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*');
});
```

Как всё же отловить проигрывание видео, и при включении другого ставить на паузу это?

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь, это вам поможет:

```js
var play;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    play = new YT.Player('play', { videoId: 'JMJXvsCLu6s', });
    document.getElementById('playYoutube1').onclick = function() {
        play.playVideo();
    };
    document.getElementById('pauseYoutube1').onclick = function() {
        play.pauseVideo();
    };
}
```

```html
<div id="play"></div>
<div id="playYoutube1">воспроизведение</div>
<div id="pauseYoutube1">пауза</div>

<script src="//www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
```

[Источник](http://shpargalkablog.ru/2014/01/pause-youtube.html).

Comment: Не нужно надеяться. Нужно объяснить, в чём заключается ваша идея и как она решает поставленный вопрос.

Comment: Что тут объяснять? От видео нужно только ID, по нему останавливай воспроизводи все что хочешь. что именно автору в коде непонятно?

Comment: Не понятен один момент, я разворачиваю ваш код здесь на stackoverflow и он не работает, почему-то, может из-за видео. Но суть ясна, попробую доработать. Спасибо!

Comment: Не работает потому что нет видео в <div id="play"></div>
Смотрите в источнике, там более подробно.